# C# stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am receiving an error in my application and i can not figure out how to resolve it.  Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers", myConnection);

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      string serverIP = rdr["ServerIP"].ToString();
      ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + serverIP);
      string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();

      foreach (string name in taskNames)
      {
         Task t = st.OpenTask(name);
         var status = t.Status;
         var recentRun = t.MostRecentRunTime;
         var nextRun = t.NextRunTime;
         var appName = t.ApplicationName;

         SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
         SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("sp_AddScheduledTasks", myConnection2);

         try
         {
            myConnection2.Open();
            myCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            myCommand2.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@ServerIP", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = serverIP;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@MostRecentRun", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = recentRun;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@NextRunTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = nextRun;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@AppName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = appName;
            myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = status;

            int rows = myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         finally
         {
            myConnection2.Close();
         }
```

The error I am receiving is with the `ExecuteNonQuery`.  It says

> InvalidCastException Failed to
>   convert parameter value from a Task to
>   a String.

I thought it had something to do with where I put the try (inside the if statement) but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I think the problem is in this line
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
If your class has a member Name try to add as the parameter t.Name.

Comment: @All - amazing how fast all of us answered this.  There are too many C# programmers in the world! ;)

Comment: small tip, you dont need to specify the dbtype. You can just use: new SqlParameter("@paramname", paramvalue);. Only for output params you need the dbtype and the size. You can also better use  the "using" keyword instead of try/finally

Comment: Dont forget to upvote the question guys :). 9 answers, 3 comments only 1 votes isn't right

Comment: Wow.  Everyone saw that one but me.  LOL.

Comment: couple more suggestions: (1) no need to check if there are rows, the while (reader.Read()) will correctly skip if there were no rows returned. (2) I would use a using statement to encapsulate those sql commands and connections. you don't want any kind of memory leak without disposing of those non managed resources.

Comment: I was considering the "using" also.  I will remove the while.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is that in

```
   myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

t is not a string?

Comment: No it is a task.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 9):

t is of type `Task` but when you pass it to your stored procedure you are passing it as `nvarchar`.

Here is your code:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

Comment: Well, I gave you +1  Basically, we all have the same answer and all at about the same time.  If we think our answer was good, we think that everyone's answer was good.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your `name` variable is indeed the `@TaskName` simply use `name`

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = name;
```

or if you override `ToString()`

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t.ToString();
```

or if you have `Name` on your `Task` object

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t.Name;
```

Comment: Crap.  I didn't realize I was using the task.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

In the line:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

I think you have to pass `t.Name` or `t.ToString()` up on the task's name (I don't know it).

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

t cannot be converted to a string. You could try `t.Name or t.ToString()` (not sure what properties are available on that class off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 5):

T is type of Task and and ado  try convert it to   string 
you should put `t.GetType().Name` or the real task name here
because we can't pass objects as parameter the only type are known sqltypes

Answer (score 4):

```
  myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

`t` is a `Task` not a string. This should probably by `name`.

Answer (score 4):

On the line:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

't' is a task, not a string. You need to get the task name instead (by the looks of it)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is on this line:

```
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("@TaskName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t;
```

You are passing the task object in instead of the name of the task.