# Call stored procedure with multiple parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# stored procedure with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201734/c-sharp-stored-procedure-with-parameters)

I am trying to call a stored procedure from c# passing in multiple parameters and can't to get it working. Here is what I have so far.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "inserttoTable @size = " + size + ", @brand = " + brand + ", @manu = " + manu + ", @t= " + id.ToString();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Size, brand and manu are all strings. inserttoTable is the stored procedure.

I get the following error : `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.`

Comment: For one thing, if they're strings, you need to surroud them with apostrophes, but this causes problems when the variables have apostrophes.  You're better off using a parameterized query as shown in my comment above.

Comment: This is vunerable to SQL injection attacks. Please reconsider using a parameterized query.

Comment: Does not look like a dup to me. Similar, yes, exact dup, no.

Answer (score 2):

check out this:

[SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have fewer problems if you use parameters and change the command type to stored procedure:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "inserttoTable";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@size", size));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@brand", brand));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@manu", manu));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@t", id.ToString()));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the best method to call a stored procedure, if you add single quotes around the string parameters, you should be fine.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "inserttoTable @size = '" + size + "', @brand = '" + brand + "', @manu = '" + manu + "', @t= '" + id.ToString() + "'"; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code is very dated and was already deprecated 10 years ago.

Comment: So why was this voted down exactly?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote down so I didn't do it