# Shorthand for create new instance if null?

Tags: c#

In Javascript I can do this:

`var myVar = returnNull() || new MyObject();`

In C# I am currenly doing this:

```
var myVar = returnObjectOrNull();

if (myVar == null) myVar = new MyObject();
```

Is there any way to shorten it in C#?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

use [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator

```
foo ?? new Foo();
```

Or in your case

```
var myVar = returnObjectOrNull() ?? new MyObject();
```

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

Answer (score 5):

Use the null coalescing operator

```
var myVar = returnObjectOrNull();

myVar = myVar ?? new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
var myvar = returnObjectOrNull() ?? new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, it's called the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
var myVar = returnObjectOrNull() ?? new MyObject();
```

Note that this operator will not evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is not null, which means that the above line of code will not create a new MyObject unless it has to.

Here's an example [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program to demonstrate:

```
void Main()
{
    var myVar = returnObjectOrNull() ?? new MyObject();
}

public MyObject returnObjectOrNull()
{
    return new MyObject();
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyObject created");
    }
}
```

This will output "MyObject created" once, meaning that there is only one object being created, in the returnObjectOrNull method, not the one in the `??` statement line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`?? Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator like;

```
var myVar = returnObjectOrNull() ?? new MyObject();
```

> The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

Comment: Lol everyone has the same answer! It's like you all copy and pasted then submitted your answer as your own.

Comment: There's only really one answer to it, so it isn't surprising that everyone's answer is pretty much the same.

Comment: @PatrickMagee Actually, it is too normal. This is a basic question and all the answer has close timestamps. Like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201734/c-sharp-stored-procedure-with-parameters It is too normal in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I know, I know, but it was funny when I refreshed everyone had the same variable names and everything xD

Comment: I think everyone just modified the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as this. If myvar is null you will get new MyObject instance otherwise you will see non-null object.

```
myvar ??= new MyObject();
```