# stored procedure select statement with multiple parameters C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

```
SqlCommand cmdadmin = new SqlCommand("loginvalidation");
cmdadmin.Connection = con;
cmdadmin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter paramadmin;
paramadmin = new SqlParameter("@vtype",drd1.ToString());
SqlParameter paramadmin1;
paramadmin1 = new SqlParameter("@username",Label1.Text);
cmdadmin.Parameters.Add(paramadmin1,paramadmin);
```

This Is My C# code

I am using Stored procedure to display the following result in select Command but I don't know how to use multiple parameters in a select statement

Comment: Just add more.. you've got 2 already, add more.

Comment: Please show us your stored procedure.

Comment: `select * from trainerdetails where emailid=@Vtype and login_code=(select login_code from login_type where login_type=@username)`

This is The Query I used In Stored Procedure

Comment: Most likely then you are not running the Execute operation your command like cmdadmin.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# stored procedure with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201734/c-sharp-stored-procedure-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this way

```
SqlCommand cmdadmin = new SqlCommand("loginvalidation");
cmdadmin.Connection = con;
cmdadmin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter[] parameters ={
                         new SqlParameter("vtype",drd1.ToString()),
                         new SqlParameter("username",Label1.Text),
                        };
foreach (var p in parameters)
   {   
       cmdadmin.Parameters.Add(parameters);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement inside stored procedure would be similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM <YourTable> WHERE Column1=@vtype <AND/OR> Column2=@username
```

Comment: `select * from trainerdetails where emailid=@Vtype
 and login_code=(select login_code from login_type where login_type=@username)`

Comment: Are you getting the result?

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple parameter, you can create an array of `SqlParameter`

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();

SqlParameter[] parameter = {
new SqlParameter("@name", "Test"), 
new SqlParameter("@age", "24")};

sql.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

in your stored procedure:

```
@name varchar(50)
@age nvarchar(10)

SELECT * 
FROM <tableName> 
WHERE Name = @name AND Age = @age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SqlCommand cmdadmin = new SqlCommand("loginvalidation");
        cmdadmin.Connection = con;
        cmdadmin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[] 
        {
            new SqlParameter("@vtype", drd1.ToString()),
            new SqlParameter("@username", Label1.Text)
        };

        cmdadmin.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
```